# Insert array into an json encoded array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have function retIKey(..):

```
function retIKey($text, $callback) {
    return json_encode([
        'inline_keyboard'=>[
            [
                ['text'=>"$text", 'callback_data'=>"$callback"]
            ]
        ],
    ]);
}
```

I have some information that I should add to this array. I want to add `['text'=>"sql1", 'callback_data'=>"sql1"]` into the array using for loop. For example, the result should be like this after the for loop:

```
function retIKey($text, $callback) {
    return json_encode([
        'inline_keyboard'=>[
            [
                ['text'=>"$text", 'callback_data'=>"$callback"], ['text'=>"sql1", 'callback_data'=>"sql2"]
            ],
[
                ['text'=>"sql2", 'callback_data'=>"sal2"]
            ]
        ],
    ]);
}
```

What should I do? How can I do this?

Comment: The result of that function is not an array, it's a blob of text that happens to be JSON. If you want to manipulate the data outside of the function, then don't encode it as JSON. Leave the data as data until you have a _reason_ to serialize it to JSON or otherwise.

Comment: @Sammitch how can I do that? I used array_unshift but it doesn't work like I want

Answer (score 0):

Your function return the array json encoded. So to add values to the array outside of the function afterwards, you have to decode the array first. After adding the values, you can encode again if needed.

It works like this:

```php
function retIKey($text, $callback)
{
    return json_encode([
        'inline_keyboard' => [
            [
                'text' => "$text",
                'callback_data' => "$callback"
            ]
        ]
    ]);
}

$jsonArray = retIKey('sql1', 'sql1');

$array = json_decode($jsonArray, true);
$array['inline_keyboard'][] = [
    'text' => 'sql2',
    'callback_data' => 'sql2'
];
```

`$array` now looks like:

```
array (size=1)
  'inline_keyboard' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'text' => string 'sql1' (length=4)
          'callback_data' => string 'sql1' (length=4)
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          'text' => string 'sql2' (length=4)
          'callback_data' => string 'sql2' (length=4)
```

If needed, you can encode the array again afterwards with:

```php
$jsonArray = json_encode($array);
```

Comment: @imGoat Is my answer helpful to you?